# Button to add entry column to r shiny datatable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, datacolumn, columnheader

I am looking to find a way to add a button to a datatable in r shiny that: 
Adds an empty column to the data table each time it is clicked (and dataframe that made the table in the first place 
Which the user can fill himself 
With numeric or text values 
And set their own column name to describe the type of entry values.

To for instance add lab note records to instrument data that is already in the shiny app manually

I am asking in case a more skilled person who has a better clue than me knows how to do this. 
I have read a bunch of pages, but at best the example I found provides 1 fixed empty column with a fixed name

> [empty column](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601291/make-a-column-in-a-basic-shiny-datatable-that-accepts-numeric-inputs&ved=2ahUKEwibzejb5PbYAhVMCewKHdHBDogQjjgwA3oECBMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2L4AtNgRaGRmQXHR8AyyX0)

A dummy table from the package : 
library(DT)

```
ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You could look at the `rhandsontable` package, and [this page](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/shiny_editTable.html) does essentially what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a button to add a new column to a R shiny datatable like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
  textInput('NewCol', 'Enter new column name'),
  radioButtons("type", "Column type:",
               c("Integer" = "integer",
                 "Floating point" = "numeric",
                 "Text" = "character")),
  actionButton("goButton", "Update Table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- mtcars
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(df())
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      if (input$type == "integer") v1 <- integer(NROW(mydata))
      if (input$type == "numeric") v1 <- numeric(NROW(mydata))
      if (input$type == "character") v1 <- character(NROW(mydata))
      newcol <- data.frame(v1)
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      mydata <<- cbind(mydata, newcol)
    }
    mydata
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}    
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

If you also need to edit the contents of the cells interactively, you can use `renderRHandsontable` instead of `renderDataTable`. Like this:

```
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  rHandsontableOutput("mytable"),
  textInput('NewCol', 'Enter new column name'),
  radioButtons("type", "Column type:",
    c("Integer" = "integer",
      "Floating point" = "numeric",
      "Text" = "character")),
  actionButton("goButton", "Update Table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- mtcars[1:5,]
  output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      if (input$type == "integer") v1 <- integer(NROW(mydata))
      if (input$type == "numeric") v1 <- numeric(NROW(mydata))
      if (input$type == "character") v1 <- character(NROW(mydata))
      newcol <- data.frame(v1)
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      mydata <<- cbind(mydata, newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(mydata, stretchH = "all")
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observe(if (!is.null(input$mytable)) mydata <<- hot_to_r(input$mytable))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Doesn't allow you to fill it with values by typing though.

Comment: Sorry - thought the question was just how to add the column.  Updated to also show how to edit.

Comment: Looks really cool! I was originally looking at possibilities to add option buttons to datatable, but this works nicely. I might consider developping autodetection of what kind of data type is entered, some safety checks etc. For now, 2 small followup questions: Is it possible to make only the newest added column editable (to protect original data), and B, update table now removes all entered values and turns them back to 0

Comment: I forgot to put in a line watching for changes to the table and writing them back to the `mydata`. Added that now.  Updata table should not reset values now.  Re making only some columns editable - probably simplest would be to use separate tables for each subset of columns (those to edit, those that are fixed).  If you need help on that, suggest to ask as a new question.

Comment: Cool. I'll see if I can find out how to make existing columns read only unless you know how to do it already