# rhandsontable & shiny: make a conditional plot depending on added columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive-programming, rhandsontable

I'd like to make a plot (ggplot) after updating a table in a shiny but I can't seem to make it work - the plot does not appear. The plot should only come up once columns are created for x and y. Ideally with points appearing as values are edited into the table. Below is some reproducible code ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471042/button-to-add-entry-column-to-r-shiny-datatable)) which I expanded on.

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  rHandsontableOutput("mytable"),
  textInput('NewCol', 'Enter new column name'),
  radioButtons("type", "Column type:",
               c("Integer" = "integer",
                 "Floating point" = "numeric",
                 "Text" = "character")),
  actionButton("goButton", "Update Table"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # g <- reactiveValues(d=NULL) #define it ouside

  mydata <- mtcars[1:5,]
  output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      if (input$type == "integer") v1 <- integer(NROW(mydata))
      if (input$type == "numeric") v1 <- numeric(NROW(mydata))
      if (input$type == "character") v1 <- character(NROW(mydata))
      newcol <- data.frame(v1)
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      mydata <<- cbind(mydata, newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(mydata, stretchH = "all")
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observe(if (!is.null(input$mytable)) mydata <<- hot_to_r(input$mytable))

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (req(mydata$x) >= 0 & req(mydata$y) >= 0) 
      ggplot(mydata, aes(x=mydata$x,y=mydata$y)) +
        geom_point()
    # else if (req(mydata$x) = 0 & req(mydata$y) = 0) {
    #   print("empty")
    # }
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: i modifies the title to be more specific, if it doesn"t suit you feel free to take it back :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how those fonctions work (`rhandsontable` and `hot_to_r`) but what you want to do seems compatible with the classic `reactiveValues` framework, like this in your server code:

```
r = reactiveValues(mydata=mtcars[1:5,])
  output$mytable = renderRHandsontable(df())
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$NewCol!="" && !is.null(input$NewCol) && input$goButton>0){
      if (input$type == "integer") v1 <- integer(NROW(r$mydata))
      if (input$type == "numeric") v1 <- numeric(NROW(r$mydata))
      if (input$type == "character") v1 <- character(NROW(r$mydata))
      newcol <- data.frame(v1)
      names(newcol) <- input$NewCol
      r$mydata <- cbind(r$mydata, newcol)
    }
    rhandsontable(r$mydata, stretchH = "all")
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observe({if (!is.null(input$mytable)) r$mydata <- hot_to_r(input$mytable)})
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(r$mydata$x) | is.null(r$mydata$y)) {return(NULL)}
      ggplot(r$mydata, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
      geom_point()})  }
```

I guess it's safer than doing global assignments, which is not recommended in general